# Array find per day React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, date

I have an array of schedule that I only want to show 1 data in the array depending on the day today.

```
{
                    schedule.map(s => {
                        let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thurdsay', 'friday', 'saturday'];
                        let date = new Date();
                        let dayIndex = date.getDay();
                        let dayName = days[dayIndex]

                        let currentSchedule = schedule.find(s => s.days == dayName)
                        if(currentSchedule){
                            return <li className="list-group-item">{currentSchedule.day}: Open: {s.open} - Close: {s.close}</li>
                        }
                    })
                }
```

current output is

```
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
```

My expected output is

for example today is saturday it will only output

```
Satruday: opening: 10:00 AM PST - closing: 10:00 PM PST
```

Comment: What is `s.days`? It sounds wrong to compare a plurally named array (or object) to `dayName`

Comment: I construct it from the schedule to the days array. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Map() function iterate through all elements of array. You should use filter() function instead of it. Try this code, it should work correctly.

```
schedule.filter(s => {
                    let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thurdsay', 'friday', 'saturday'];
                    let date = new Date();
                    let dayIndex = date.getDay();
                    let dayName = days[dayIndex];

                    let currentSchedule = schedule.find(s => s.days == dayName);
                    if(currentSchedule){
                        return <li className="list-group-item">{currentSchedule.day}: Open: {s.open} - Close: {s.close}</li>
                    }
                })
```

But it`s also better to take out duplicate code into the definition of scheduler.

```
let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thurdsay', 'friday', 'saturday'];
let date = new Date();
let dayIndex = date.getDay();
let dayName = days[dayIndex];
```

Comment: Or even leave let currentSchedule = schedule.find(s => s.days == dayName) and only get rid of wrapping your code in schedule.map()

Comment: Hi, still the same output but the days array is not outputing. When I remove the schedule.map() my code is not being read by react.

Comment: What is schedule in your code? Show please

Comment: it is an array of object that includes : open and close: for ex: open: "10:00am" close: "10:00pm"